# is there a way in R to fill NA's with all possible values by a dplyr group?

Tags: r

say I have:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'),
              int=c(NA,NA,1,2,3,2, NA),
               ab=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'))
df
  ID int ab
1  1  NA  a
2  1  NA  a
3  1   1  b
4  1   2  b
5  1   3  b
6  1   2  b
7  1  NA  c
```

for all `int` values for non-NA group `ab`, I want to extend those values to the other `ab` which would require inserting extra rows. So I want values 1, 2,and 3 show up for ab==a and ab==c. Something like:

```
dfwant<-data.frame(ID=c('1','1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'),
               int=c(NA, NA,NA,1,2,3,2, NA, NA, NA),
               ab=c('a','a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'),
               want=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2, 1,2,3))
   ID int ab want
1   1  NA  a    1
2   1  NA  a    2
3   1  NA  a    3
4   1   1  b    1
5   1   2  b    2
6   1   3  b    3
7   1   2  b    2
8   1  NA  c    1
9   1  NA  c    2
10  1  NA  c    3
```

maybe there's another way, but I want to have the `int` 1, 2, 3 values associated with all `ab` values within an `ID`. Maybe I need more columns, please help

EDIT: Also want it to work for different groups with different number of unique `int`:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'),
               int=c(NA,NA,1,2,3,2, NA, NA,NA,5,6,7,8, NA),
               ab=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f'))

   ID int ab
1   1  NA  a
2   1  NA  a
3   1   1  b
4   1   2  b
5   1   3  b
6   1   2  b
7   1  NA  c
8   2  NA  d
9   2  NA  d
10  2   5  e
11  2   6  e
12  2   7  e
13  2   8  e
14  2  NA  f



   ID want ab
1   1    1  a
2   1    2  a
3   1    3  a
4   1    1  b
5   1    2  b
6   1    3  b
7   1    2  b
8   1    1  c
9   1    2  c
10  1    3  c
11  2    5  d
12  2    6  d
13  2    7  d
14  2    8  d
15  2    5  e
16  2    6  e
17  2    7  e
18  2    8  e
19  2    5  f
20  2    6  f
21  2    7  f
22  2    8  f
```

Comment: Can it happen that a group like a or c has some NA elements and some other non-NA elements or is it either all NA or al non-NA? Also in this case, group b is the one that is filled and should serve as source. Can there be more than one group that is filled?

Comment: Are you replaceing when all values are NA by group `df %>% group_by(ID, ab) %>% summarise(want = list(if(all(is.na(int))) 1:3 else int)) %>% unnest(c(want))`

Comment: all NA within ```ab```group or not. Sometimes I can have ```ab``` within an ID just a and b (for example ID==2 may have only ab==a or ab==b) but the principle would be the same (extend the values in a to b). No, only one group per ID will be filled

Comment: What is your expected output for the new example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(want = int) %>%
    group_by(ID, ab) %>%
    complete(want =  unique(na.omit(.$want))) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(want))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID, ab [3]
#   ID    ab     want   int
#   <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1     a         1    NA
# 2 1     a         2    NA
# 3 1     a         3    NA
# 4 1     b         1     1
# 5 1     b         2     2
# 6 1     b         2     2
# 7 1     b         3     3
# 8 1     c         1    NA
# 9 1     c         2    NA
#10 1     c         3    NA
```

---

For the updated data

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
     mutate(want = int) %>%
     group_split(ID = as.character(ID)) %>%
     map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
                   group_by(ab) %>%
                   complete(want =  unique(na.omit(.$want))) %>%
                   filter(!is.na(want))) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     fill(ID, .direction = 'downup')
# A tibble: 22 x 4
#   ab     want ID      int
#   <fct> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a         1 1        NA
# 2 a         2 1        NA
# 3 a         3 1        NA
# 4 b         1 1         1
# 5 b         2 1         2
# 6 b         2 1         2
# 7 b         3 1         3
# 8 c         1 1        NA
# 9 c         2 1        NA
#10 c         3 1        NA
# … with 12 more rows
```

Comment: this breaks down when different numbers of distinct int, for example: ```df<-data.frame(ID=c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'),
               int=c(NA,NA,1,2,3,2, NA, NA,NA,5,6,7,8, NA),
               ab=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f'))```

Comment: maybe there is another way to do it, I'd be ok with making more columns if I have to so long as all ```int``` values show up with all ```ab```

Comment: @biostatguy12 the code is still running without any error.  I am curious about your expected output for that case as your question is `R to fill NA's with all possible values by a dplyr group?`

Comment: yes for example in the df I have made in the comment, I would want ```want``` to only have 1, 2, 3 for a and c, NOT for d and f. Similarly I don't want 5, 6,7,8 showing up in ID==1

Comment: @biostatguy12 just saw your updated post.  Can you check my updated solution